# pgf-pie aside block trouble

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I have trouble with a pie chart (`pgf-pie`).
I can't put pie in block aside why?

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
 \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
   \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{pblue} ##1
}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(2.0, 0.55)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection


}

\begin{aside}
  \section{Personal Skills}
     \includegraphics[scale=0.62]{img/personal.png} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}%there is bug
            \pie [square]{40/A,30/B,20/C,10/D}
        \end{tikzpicture}
         ~
\end{aside}
```

output:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.64 ^^I^^I\begin{tikzpicture}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no w in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 6 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.65 ^^I^^I^^I\pie[square]{40/A,30/B,20/C,10/D}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of problems with this code:

- no document class (no `\documentclass` command)
- no `\begin{document}` and no `\end{document}`
- `\headingfont` is undefined
- `pblue` is not a defined color
- the image is not found (your file `img/personal.png` is not available here)

The mentioned bug "*Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.*" comes from the `flushright` environment. Remove it to see that.  You could use `\raggedleft` later within the `aside` document text, or `\hfill`.